# 12.04 Multiple screens Rotation Issue

Tags: resolution

I have an EeePC netbook running Windows XP and Ubuntu 12.04 where I connect a 19" monitor.
I want to set 1440x900 resolution for the monitor but when I press Apply the [Rotation] options are only [Clockwise] and [Counterclockwise], meaning no [Normal] option like when it's set to 1024x768.

I tried ARandR but when I set 1440x900 the computer stops responding.
I also tried a lower resolution and it did the same.

I know it is possible, because Windows does it, not to mention Intel Graphics utility, which allows me to set the monitor as primary screen and actually do it.

Am I doing something wrong?
Please consider I haven't used Linux for too long, so I would appreciate it if any command line instructions were "for dummies".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Corrected: I remembered a previous installation with the same issue complaining about not being able to enable the 3d desktop effects for such large one: 1024+1440=2464x2464. It also mentioned that the largest was 2048x... Anyway, the solution is to **log in using the 2d desktop**. You can do this from the login screen clicking on the ubuntu logo next to the username.

Cheers!

Pedro.